# Drawing a simple line chart using Swift

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I am writing a Swift program using Xcode 9.2 for the MacOS with the objecting of displaying a simple line chart with three points.

The program's objective is to create a line graph using apple's core graphics. It is a horizontal line graph with three points, one at the center and at each end. If the mouse pointer is over the center point I want some text to display like "xyz" and when the mouse moves away the text would disappear. The end points will have labels containing numbers but for now let's call them "min" and "max".

Using XCode's playground, so far I have managed to accomplish to display a very clunky line graph using the following code:

```
class MyView : NSView {
   override func draw(_ rect: NSRect) {
       NSColor.green.setFill()
       var path = NSBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
       path.fill()

  let leftDot = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 20)
  path = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: leftDot)
  NSColor.black.setFill()
  path.fill()

  let rightDot = NSRect(x: 90, y: 0, width: 10, height: 20)
  path = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: rightDot)
  NSColor.black.setFill()
  path.fill()

  let centerDot = NSRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 10, height: 20)
  path = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: centerDot)
  NSColor.black.setFill()
  path.fill()

  }
}

let viewRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 10)
let myEmptyView = MyView(frame: viewRect)
```

The code produces a clunky looking line graph as follows:

[image: Ugly line chart]

The chart below is from Excel and this line chart is much cleaner and is what I am looking for but I want the line to be horizontal instead of diagonal.

[image: Excel line chart]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are not drawing a line. You are filling a rectangle.

Comment: I am new to Swift and MacOS programming so I approached it by filling a rectangle. How would you draw a line?

Answer (score 5):

To draw a horizontal line similar to the sample image you provided, I took your sample code and modified it. This would give this result:

[image: horizontal line]

The code would look like this then:

```
override func draw(_ rect: NSRect) {
    NSColor(red: 103/255, green: 146/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1).set()
    let line = NSBezierPath()
    line.move(to: NSMakePoint(10, 5))
    line.line(to: NSMakePoint(90, 5))
    line.lineWidth = 2
    line.stroke()

    NSColor(red: 163/255, green: 189/255, blue: 218/255, alpha: 1).setFill()

    let origins = [NSPoint(x: 10, y: 1),
                   NSPoint(x: 50, y: 1),
                   NSPoint(x: 90, y: 1)]

    let size = NSSize(width: 8, height: 8)

    for origin in origins {
        let quad = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: NSRect(origin: origin, size: size), xRadius: 2, yRadius: 2)
        quad.fill()
        quad.stroke()
    }
}
```

**Update for iOS**

Due to a request in the comments section here the iOS variant:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    UIColor(red: 103/255, green: 146/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1).set()
    let line = UIBezierPath()
    line.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y:5))
    line.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y:5))
    line.lineWidth = 2
    line.stroke()

    UIColor(red: 163/255, green: 189/255, blue: 218/255, alpha: 1).setFill()

    let origins = [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 1),
                   CGPoint(x: 50, y: 1),
                   CGPoint(x: 90, y: 1)]

    let size = CGSize(width: 8, height: 8)

    for origin in origins {
        let quad = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size), cornerRadius: 2)
        quad.fill()
        quad.stroke()
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a CAShapeLayer sublayer whose path property is a UIBezierPath to the UIView.

Comment: How would you do this for iPhone apps (since NSView is for MacOS)?